# JDBC (Microsoft SQL Server): No suitable driver found for url

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, groovy, database-connection

I am trying to connect to an existing DB which is host on a ESXI server and it seems I cannot properly locate the driver.

The code I use is the following:

```
new ConnectToDb('jdbc:sqlserver:sqltest3:CI-ESXI', 'USER', 'PASSWORD', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

    ConnectToDb(String url, String user, String password, String driver) {
        Class.forName(driver)
        database =  groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)
    }
```

I obtain the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc:sqlserver:sqltest3:CI-ESXI

Also, I tried the following, java style, code:

```
void connect(String url, String user, String password, String driver) throws SQLException {
    if (null == stmt || stmt.isClosed()) {
        // Create a connection to the database
        if (database_url == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Cannot connect to database, connection URL is null.")
        }

        Properties  database_infos = new Properties()

        database_infos.put("user", user)
        database_infos.put("password", password)
        database_infos.put("driver", driver)

        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, database_infos)
        stmt = connection.createStatement()
    }
}
```

Which returns the same exception.

Actually, a direct call to `DriverManager.getDriver(driver)` returns the same exception.

The driver is added to the POM.xml file the following way:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

It is added to the classpath and I can import it in any java file in the following way `import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` without error

I am working using IntelliJ IDEA in a Groovy project but I can reproduce the error in Eclipse in a pure Java project. So it does not seems to be langage/IDE based.

So now I am a bit clueless about that, any idea ?

Comment: Is it in your classpath at runtime?

Comment: Well I believe it is, if you ask the question I supposed that the fact that the import is working does not guarantee it is in the class path at runtime. How can I verify that ? Isn't that the role of the Class.forname(driver) call ?

Comment: Import statements are resolved at compile time (java compiler, `javac`).  Do you see these error messages inside your IDE, or outside?

Comment: A JDBC driver has nothing to do with SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Why do you think that `jdbc:sqlserver:sqltest3:CI-ESXI` is a valid JDBC url for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver? It doesn't match the URL syntax in [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 1):

So i found it, the error message was totally misleading as the issue was in the URL which should be:

```
'jdbc:sqlserver://sqltest3'
```

If the `//` are not present, then the connectedProperties are returned to null, and there's no driver provided, hence the resulting error message.

Comment: So you didn't show the URL in the first place.  Interesting however, sounds like either the documentation for the sqlserver driver is insufficient, or you have it into an actual bug.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The URL the OP used was simply not syntactically correct, and drivers are expected to ignore URLs they don't recognize. That in turn will cause the 'No suitable driver found' error. The syntax of the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC url is documented at [Building the Connection URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Yes this is what happen, instead of telling me "your url is invalid", the sqlserverdriver nullify all the properties and then run into "I have no driver"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Interesting.  Apparently it's been too long since I read up on this - I believed when the driver matched the "sqlserver" bit, then it was responsible for handling the URL and not just silently ignore it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The javadoc only says _"The driver should return "null" if it realizes it is the wrong kind of driver to connect to the given URL."_. So they should accept URLs they recognize, and return `null` otherwise. If they recognize the URL, but something fails, they should throw an exception. There is no requirement in JDBC that says that if you support a certain protocol-prefix, that you must process all URLs with that prefix: it is even perfectly acceptable if drivers use the same prefix, as long as you keep in mind that the first to accept and successfully connect 'wins'.

Comment: @Zangdar What do you mean with _"nullify all the properties"_. If the driver removes things from the provided `Properties` object, that would be a bug that should be reported on https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc (assuming you're using the latest version).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would consider "matching the sqlserver bit" to be a yes to "am I the right driver"?  Apparently others don't.  Good to know.   It just sounds strange - perhaps somebody may try to replicate the behavior.  OP may have made a cut-paste error here.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel The "consolidatedProperties" variable created and used by the driverManager is set to "null" and returned like this to methods that request it. Hence all properties that you specified to the getConnection method are lost.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen to replicate behavior, simply take a working code sample, remove the "//" from the url, you should get this error

Comment: @Zangdar Please be precise. Who sets what to `null`, and where? `DriverManager` has no `consolidatedProperties` variable, and even if it had, the called driver cannot set a variable to null in the caller.

Comment: @zangdar interesting. Sounds trivial to create a MVP showing what you see then.

Comment: Yes I will do as soon as I can